# URDF surface tags are not propagated to gazebo

Tags: ros2, urdf

I am struggling to set friction to my model in gazebo. Issue is it is frictionless. It is walking in place and cannot move. I set my tags according to this document [SDFormat](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision#surface_friction) but they are not visible in link inspection in Gazebo. Looks like surface tag is not propagated at all.  I got gazebo 11.10.2 . Abd ros2 humble. Below is the screenshot:[image]

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshots, it's generally better to provide any text/xml/etc formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to insert all tags inside < gazebo reference="link_name"> tag under < robot> tag and not under < link> tag. Here is document [GazeboURDF](http://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf&cat=connect_ros#%3Ccollision%3Eand%3Cvisual%3Eelements). Like this works for me:

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
<gazebo reference="link_name">
    <minDepth>0.01</minDepth>
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <mu2>0.23</mu2>
</gazebo>
<link name="link_name">
(other tags ...)
</link>
</robot>
```